Uniform random variables and integrals
Let $Y, X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots, X_{n}$ be iid $\operatorname{Unif}\left(0,1\right)$ random variables:

Sometimes, I have to find a probability of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\operatorname{f}\left(X_{1},
\cdots, X_{n}\right) \geq Y\right)
$$
I think (not sure, but it always gave me the
right answer) that it is equal to
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
\operatorname{f}\left(x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}\right) \,{\rm d}x_{1}\ldots{\rm d}x_{n}
$$
but I never seen a formal proof of this equality.
For $n = 1$ I feel like there is an idea of "area under the curve" so the integral makes sense.

Is this equality true?

Your integral does not mention $Y$ or $y$ and looks closer to being $\mathbb{E}\big[\operatorname{f}\left(X_{1},
\cdots, X_{n}\right)\big]$

It's close to true. Assuming $f$ to take only non-negative values, a correct formula is
$$\Bbb P(f(X_1,\cdots,X_n) \geq Y)
=\int_0^1 ...\int_0^1 \min[f(x_1,\cdots,x_n),1]\, dx_1\cdots dx_2.
$$
Your formula  is correct as written if $0\le f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\le 1$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in[0,1]^n$.

Were you answering to a deleted comment or did you say 'no' because something's wrong with your answer?

I was responding to a now-deleted comment. I'll delete this comment soon.

$\def\E{\mathbb{E}} \def\P{\mathbb{P}}$ It can't be true as written. Your expression computes $\E f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$. If $f$ is the constant function $2$ then its expectation is $2$, but the probability $\P(2\ge Y)$ is $1$.

Agreed. Somthing's wrong

The correct computation is to integrate the function 1 over the subset of $[0,1]^{n+1}$ (with last coordinate labeled $y$) where $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ge y$.  That’s generally a lot harder than the calculation you indicate.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{{\cal P}\pars{y}}$ the coveted probability$\ldots$.
Then,
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{{\cal P}\pars{y}} & \equiv
\left.
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}\,\right\vert_
{\,\on{f}\pars{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}}\ >\ y}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
\Theta\pars{ \on{f}\pars{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}} - y}\,
\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}}}
\\ & \Theta\ \mbox{is the}\ Heaviside\ Step\ Function.
\\[5mm] & {\bf Example}: \on{f}\pars{x_{1},x_{2}} = x_{1}x_{2}
\\ & \mbox{The result becomes}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{y \in \left(-\infty,0\right]} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{1 - y + y\ln\pars{y}} & \mbox{if} &
\ds{y \in \pars{0,1}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} && \mbox{Otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$\ds{\LARGE \underline{but}\quad}$ $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x_{1}x_{2}\,
\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2} = {1 \over 4}}$
